# how can I set local component as source of iframe in react?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have an iframe in one of my react component. I want to display another component inside that iframe.

Something like this. Any idea how can I achieve it?

```
import AnotherComponent from './';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <iframe src=<AnotherComponent /> />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` property of an `iframe` should be an URL.

Thus, this URL can target a React application which contains the component you want to display in this iframe.

Comment: I am using react router. can I give that component's route as src for iframe?

Comment: Nope, only URLs. But why do you want to use an iframe to display a React component ?

Comment: I am implementing video.js with in-video modal. 
in that modal i want to show content of another component.

I have already done it using angularjs and iframe with URL.

Comment: You can give the iframe the url of your application and then make it handle this url to render the appropriate component. But you can't pass JavaScript directly in the src property of the iframe.